# Storing datatables for reuse in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My pages load very slowly because I query the database each time a page loads and a few of the queries are rather large. Is there a way to store the datatables or any other data for reuse when the page is loaded again?

I am making a small dashboard with ASP.NET Core MVC that will display metrics with chart.js and google charts on a few pages.

I am new to programming. I just recently heard of MemoryCache but I was not sure if that would help me. Any ideas or direction would be very helpful.

Comment: In regards of `slow performing query` you can use `MemoryCache`  undoubtedly. You could have a look on [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Feel fee to share your problem if you encounter any during implementation. [Here is the sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/performance/caching/memory/samples/6.0/CachingMemorySample)

Comment: If your data is NOT realtime you could think of generating the required data periodically/scheduled on your database and store them in a table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. My pages are loading significantly faster. I will look into populating the MemoryCache serverside to keep the pages loading fast for the users. Thanks again. I cant believe I had not heard of this before.